# GWT Project doesn't load data from RPC when deployed

Tags: java, gwt, rpc

I got a little problem with my GWT project.

I have a class A(client) with a List Object L1. When a button in A is clicked files are being read on the serverside and a list is being returned through RPC which is then stored in L1 and then displayed in a table. It all works perfectly fine offline. However if i deploy the app it doesn't seem to work. The strangest thing is: 1 of the files is working and i can display the data of it in the table (the smallest file). If I push an other button though (and thus reading an other file on the serverside) nothing gets displayed on the table. It does seem to read and store it in L1 on A but I'm not quite sure about that.
On the log files I get no Errors or Warning so I don't understand why it isn't working. Maybe it isnt running fast enough or something?

The only info i get from the logs (only info and not a warning/error): "This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application." It appears randomly when clicking on the buttons (otherwise there is no info at all... just a log that its being pushed) and the latency is really high on the log with the info (3-7k ms) but just fine on the ones without info. The instances it gives me don't exist.

This is the class where the Method is called (not the full class):

```
public class DatasetMenu{
    private DataImportServiceClientImpl importer;
    public void historyChangeState(String Abstimmung){
        importer.readInput(Abstimmung);
    }
```

This is the clientside code:

```
public class DataImportServiceClientImpl{
    private DataImportServiceAsync service;
    public DatasetMenu menu;
    public DataImportServiceClientImpl(String url){
        this.service = GWT.create(DataImportService.class);
        ServiceDefTarget endpoint = (ServiceDefTarget) this.service;
        endpoint.setServiceEntryPoint(url);

        this.menu=new DatasetMenu(this);
    }
    public void readInput(String Abstimmung){
        this.service.readInput(Abstimmung, new DefaultCallback());
    }
    private class DefaultCallback implements AsyncCallback {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            System.out.println("An Error has occured!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Object result) {
            if(result instanceof List<?>){
            List<List<Raumeinheit>> temp = (List<List<Raumeinheit>>) result;
            menu.setData(temp);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

This is the code on the server side:

```
public class DataImportServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements DataImportService{

    @Override
    public List<List<Raumeinheit>> readInput(String Abstimmung){
        List<String> fileList=new ArrayList<String>();
        fileList.add("files/" + Abstimmung + ".b.csv");
        fileList.add("files/" + Abstimmung + ".k.csv");
        System.out.println(fileList.get(0));
        List<List <String[]> > total2 = new ArrayList<List <String[]> >();
        String[] values;
        for(int i =0;i<fileList.size();i++){
        List<String[]> total = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        File file = new File(fileList.get(i));
        try{
            Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
            while(inputStream.hasNext()){
                String data = inputStream.nextLine();
                values = data.split(";");
                total.add(values);
            }
            inputStream.close();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        total2.add(total);
        }
        List< List<Raumeinheit> > result = new ArrayList<List<Raumeinheit>>();
        for(int i = 0;i<total2.size();i++){
            List<Raumeinheit> temp = new ArrayList<Raumeinheit>();
            for(int j=0;j<total2.get(i).size();j++){
                if(i==1){
                temp.add(new Raumeinheit(total2.get(i).get(j)[0],Integer.parseInt(total2.get(i).get(j)[1]),Integer.parseInt(total2.get(i).get(j)[2]),Integer.parseInt(total2.get(i).get(j)[3]),Double.parseDouble(total2.get(i).get(j)[4]), Double.parseDouble(total2.get(i).get(j)[5]), Double.parseDouble(total2.get(i).get(j)[6])));
                }
                else{
                temp.add(new Raumeinheit(Integer.parseInt(total2.get(i).get(j)[0]),total2.get(i).get(j)[1],Integer.parseInt(total2.get(i).get(j)[2]),Integer.parseInt(total2.get(i).get(j)[3]),Integer.parseInt(total2.get(i).get(j)[4]),Double.parseDouble(total2.get(i).get(j)[5]), Double.parseDouble(total2.get(i).get(j)[6]), Double.parseDouble(total2.get(i).get(j)[7])));
                }
            }
            result.add(temp);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

As I said it works perfectly offline so don't worry about the serverside code. Online it only works with 1 file of the 8 we have.

The servlets:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>DataImportServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.se.sprint1.server.DataImportServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DataImportServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/sprint1/DataImport</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Hope you can help me. 
Thanks in Advance

EDIT: Code

Comment: Without posting some code, it will be impossible to help. Can you post the server call?

Comment: I wasn't sure what to post since i don't know what exactly is going wrong and I have a "lot" of code. Added several things which might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the service call to:

```
   public void readInput(String Abstimmung){
      this.service.readInput(Abstimmung, new AsyncCallback<List<List<Raumeinheit>>(){
          @Override
          public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
              System.out.println("An Error has occured!");
              // show an error message
              Window.alert("An error has occured!!"); 
          }

          @Override
          public void onSuccess(List<List<Raumeinheit>> result) {
              menu.setData(result);
          }
      });
    }
```

There is no need to check the result. If you got an error after this change, check the interfaces. Do not use the return type Object. This will let GWT generate a lot of unneccessary code.

Also, I would change this: Throw an exception if there is problem on the server. In your case of an exception on the server, you print an exception and the code goes on as if nothing happens. This might be your problem. If you got a `FileNotFoundException` throw an exception and handle this on the client side.

Comment: I added the check for result afterwards (wasn't working without it either). I also tried not using object as return type and the filenotfound exception shouldnt solve it either since: 1. It's working offline so unless the deploy doesnt mess up the "filesystem" it should be ok. 2. We have an other function with the same technique to access the files and there its working. But thanks for the effort anyway.